# R program for sorting data frame is giving me incorrect output

Tags: r

I want to sort a data frame called final_out which has columns "col1","col2","col3".

I call the function using : best("MD", "pneumonia")

I want to sort it in ascending order by col2 values, and break ties using col3 values alphabetical order
before sorting it looks like this:

```
     col1 col2                                      col3
1867   MD 12.5                    MERITUS MEDICAL CENTER
1868   MD 12.7     UNIVERSITY OF MARYLAND MEDICAL CENTER
1869   MD   13            PRINCE GEORGES HOSPITAL CENTER
1870   MD  9.6                       HOLY CROSS HOSPITAL
1871   MD  9.8               FREDERICK MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
1872   MD 11.5                 HARFORD MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
1873   MD  9.5               SAINT JOSEPH MEDICAL CENTER
1874   MD 11.2                  MERCY MEDICAL CENTER INC
1875   MD 10.2               JOHNS HOPKINS HOSPITAL, THE
1876   MD 11.1                      SAINT AGNES HOSPITAL
1877   MD  9.7               SINAI HOSPITAL OF BALTIMORE
1878   MD  9.6                      BON SECOURS HOSPITAL
1879   MD  9.3    MEDSTAR FRANKLIN SQUARE MEDICAL CENTER
1880   MD   11             WASHINGTON ADVENTIST HOSPITAL
1881   MD 13.5          GARRETT COUNTY MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
1882   MD  9.3         MEDSTAR MONTGOMERY MEDICAL CENTER
1883   MD 10.6         PENINSULA REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER
1884   MD  9.9                         SUBURBAN HOSPITAL
1885   MD   12               ANNE ARUNDEL MEDICAL CENTER
1886   MD 11.3           MEDSTAR UNION MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
1887   MD 12.6  WESTERN MARYLAND REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER
1888   MD 13.1             MEDSTAR SAINT MARY'S HOSPITAL
1889   MD 10.7      JOHNS HOPKINS BAYVIEW MEDICAL CENTER
1890   MD 11.2             CHESTER RIVER HOSPITAL CENTER
1891   MD  9.9            UNION HOSPITAL OF CECIL COUNTY
1892   MD  9.7                   CARROLL HOSPITAL CENTER
1893   MD  9.2                   MEDSTAR HARBOR HOSPITAL
1894   MD 14.2                    CIVISTA MEDICAL CENTER
1895   MD 10.6               MEMORIAL HOSPITAL AT EASTON
1896   MD 10.8                MARYLAND GENERAL  HOSPITAL
1897   MD 10.1                 CALVERT MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
1898   MD 12.6                 NORTHWEST HOSPITAL CENTER
1899   MD 12.7      BALTIMORE WASHINGTON  MEDICAL CENTER
1900   MD  7.4          GREATER BALTIMORE MEDICAL CENTER
1901   MD 12.9         EDWARD MCCREADY MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
1902   MD 10.1            HOWARD COUNTY GENERAL HOSPITAL
1903   MD 12.9           UPPER CHESAPEAKE MEDICAL CENTER
1904   MD   11              DOCTORS'  COMMUNITY HOSPITAL
1905   MD 11.7         SOUTHERN MARYLAND HOSPITAL CENTER
1906   MD 10.6            LAUREL REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER
1907   MD  8.4           MEDSTAR GOOD SAMARITAN HOSPITAL
1908   MD 11.7            SHADY GROVE ADVENTIST HOSPITAL
1909   MD   11                  FORT WASHINGTON HOSPITAL
1910   MD 10.8                 ATLANTIC GENERAL HOSPITAL
1911   MD 12.6 VA MARYLAND HEALTHCARE SYSTEM - BALTIMORE
```

after using final_out <- final_out[order(final_out$col2,final_out$col3),] it looks like this:

```
     col1 col2                                      col3
1897   MD 10.1                 CALVERT MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
1902   MD 10.1            HOWARD COUNTY GENERAL HOSPITAL
1875   MD 10.2               JOHNS HOPKINS HOSPITAL, THE
1906   MD 10.6            LAUREL REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER
1895   MD 10.6               MEMORIAL HOSPITAL AT EASTON
1883   MD 10.6         PENINSULA REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER
1889   MD 10.7      JOHNS HOPKINS BAYVIEW MEDICAL CENTER
1910   MD 10.8                 ATLANTIC GENERAL HOSPITAL
1896   MD 10.8                MARYLAND GENERAL  HOSPITAL
1904   MD   11              DOCTORS'  COMMUNITY HOSPITAL
1909   MD   11                  FORT WASHINGTON HOSPITAL
1880   MD   11             WASHINGTON ADVENTIST HOSPITAL
1876   MD 11.1                      SAINT AGNES HOSPITAL
1890   MD 11.2             CHESTER RIVER HOSPITAL CENTER
1874   MD 11.2                  MERCY MEDICAL CENTER INC
1886   MD 11.3           MEDSTAR UNION MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
1872   MD 11.5                 HARFORD MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
1908   MD 11.7            SHADY GROVE ADVENTIST HOSPITAL
1905   MD 11.7         SOUTHERN MARYLAND HOSPITAL CENTER
1885   MD   12               ANNE ARUNDEL MEDICAL CENTER
1867   MD 12.5                    MERITUS MEDICAL CENTER
1898   MD 12.6                 NORTHWEST HOSPITAL CENTER
1911   MD 12.6 VA MARYLAND HEALTHCARE SYSTEM - BALTIMORE
1887   MD 12.6  WESTERN MARYLAND REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER
1899   MD 12.7      BALTIMORE WASHINGTON  MEDICAL CENTER
1868   MD 12.7     UNIVERSITY OF MARYLAND MEDICAL CENTER
1901   MD 12.9         EDWARD MCCREADY MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
1903   MD 12.9           UPPER CHESAPEAKE MEDICAL CENTER
1869   MD   13            PRINCE GEORGES HOSPITAL CENTER
1888   MD 13.1             MEDSTAR SAINT MARY'S HOSPITAL
1881   MD 13.5          GARRETT COUNTY MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
1894   MD 14.2                    CIVISTA MEDICAL CENTER
1900   MD  7.4          GREATER BALTIMORE MEDICAL CENTER
1907   MD  8.4           MEDSTAR GOOD SAMARITAN HOSPITAL
1893   MD  9.2                   MEDSTAR HARBOR HOSPITAL
1879   MD  9.3    MEDSTAR FRANKLIN SQUARE MEDICAL CENTER
1882   MD  9.3         MEDSTAR MONTGOMERY MEDICAL CENTER
1873   MD  9.5               SAINT JOSEPH MEDICAL CENTER
1878   MD  9.6                      BON SECOURS HOSPITAL
1870   MD  9.6                       HOLY CROSS HOSPITAL
1892   MD  9.7                   CARROLL HOSPITAL CENTER
1877   MD  9.7               SINAI HOSPITAL OF BALTIMORE
1871   MD  9.8               FREDERICK MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
1884   MD  9.9                         SUBURBAN HOSPITAL
1891   MD  9.9            UNION HOSPITAL OF CECIL COUNTY
```

As you can see, the col2 values are not arranged properly. It has numbers above 10 first, then starts from 7.4 and then goes up.

I experienced the same issue when I only sorted it with col2 without the col3 tie breaker

the entire code is shown below:

```
best <- function(state,outcome){
  
  if(outcome == "heart attack")
  {
    colnam = 11
  }
  else if(outcome == "heart failure")
  {
    colnam = 17
  }
  else if(outcome == "pneumonia")
  {
    colnam = 23
  }
  else
  {
    stop("invalid outcome")
  }
  outie = read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv")
  if((state %in% outie$State) == FALSE)
  {
    stop("invalid state")
  }
  col1 <- c(outie[7])
  col2 <- c("rate"=outie[colnam])
 
  col3 <- c(outie[2])

  final_out <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3)
  colnames(final_out) <- c("col1","col2","col3")

 

  rownames(final_out) <- NULL
  final_out <- final_out[(final_out$col1 == state),]
  final_out <- final_out[order(final_out$col2,final_out$col3),]
  
  final_out

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you dput the data? To me your ordering seems to make sense for a character column, everything with 1 is first, than all the higher numbers. Are you sure the col2 is numeric?

Comment: It looks like col2 is arranged in *alphabetical* order. Are you sure that it is coded as numeric? Please post the results of `str(final_out)`

Comment: Thank you all for pointing it out! Sorry if this was a trivial problem I didnt notice.